# Ext.Net error in razon engine @Html.X(). 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'X'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, ext.net

I am trying to use Ext.Net in MVC 4.

In razor engine i am trying with an example like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "";    
}

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ext.NET Examples</title>
    </head>
    <body>    
        @Html.X().ResourceManager()

        @(Html.X().TabPanel()
            .Height(300)
            .Items(items => {
                items.Add(Html.X().Panel().Title("Test"));
            }));
    </body>
</html>
```

When i run i recieve this error in the browser:

> CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'X' and no extension method 'X' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html.X is the MVC helper for Ext.NET which is an .NET version of extJS/Sencha. So most likely you didn't install/configure the Ext.NET properly.

I suggest you check via your project's nuget packages manager if Ext.NET is installed and then go to their website and check what is the proper web.config configuration to make it all work. Here is the link:

http://www.ext.net/

Comment: i finally resolved it. The thing is that i install Ext.Net using Nuget by the command:

`PM> Install-Package Ext.NET`

But when i explored the reference Ext.NET it seems that Ext.NET.MVC was missing, so i installed this dll by using:

`PM> Install-Package Ext.NET.MVC`

Thats solve my problem.